# App is crashing while making custom listview using text and images

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

The app is crashing everytime when I am trying to run the following code.
Here is the logcat

```
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.admin.reviews, PID: 6558
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.reviews/com.example.admin.reviews.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ListView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ListView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.admin.reviews.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945) 
10-21 12:49:20.686 6558-6558/com.example.admin.reviews E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
               ListView list;
               String []  username;
               String [] desc;
               int [] propic={R.drawable.img,R.drawable.download,R.drawable.images,R.drawable.download1,
                       R.drawable.images2,R.drawable.download2};

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           Resources r= getResources();

           username = r.getStringArray(R.array.User_names);
           desc= r.getStringArray(R.array.description);

           list= (ListView) list.findViewById(R.id.listView);
           ReviewsAdapter adapter=new ReviewsAdapter(this,username,propic,desc);
           list.setAdapter(adapter);

       }
   }
   class ReviewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
       Context context;
       int[] profilepic;
       String[] nameArray;
       String[] desc1;
       ReviewsAdapter(Context c,String[] User_names,int dp[],String[] description)
       {super(c, R.layout.row_struct, R.id.textView, User_names);
           this.context=c;
           this.profilepic=dp;
           this.nameArray=User_names;
           this.desc1=description;
       }

       @Override
       public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
           LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_struct,parent,false);

           ImageView myImage=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
           TextView  myUsername=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
           TextView  myDescription=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

           myImage.setImageResource(profilepic[position]);
           myUsername.setText(nameArray[position]);
           myDescription.setText(desc1[position]);

           return row;

       }
}
```

Comment: Can you format your code and add some details ?

Comment: Oh my god...Format your code...Post more details too...

Comment: post the code where you are setting adapter to list view.Its only logcat.I think error is at initialization of the listview(findViewById).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know what is NullPointerException?

You are trying to call method on `list` object which is not created yet. `list` is null here:

```
list = (ListView) list.findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Moreover, you don't need to search list inside the same list. It should be just:

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
```